# PyQt setup for Qt 4.7.4

Tags: python, qt, compilation, pyqt, configure

I try to install PyQt to develop Python apps using Qt.
I downloaded SIP and PyQt4 from http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk and compiled the packages.

But I encountered a problem while compiling PyQt4:

I ran python configure.py in the Terminal and I got:

```
Error: Make sure you have a working Qt v4 qmake on your PATH or use the -q
argument to explicitly specify a working Qt v4 qmake.
```

I looked in Qt settings and i saw the path for qmake defined here 'home/user/.QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin/qmake'. Where else should be this path set up?

And how can i configure qt so i can write code directly into Qt Creator and execute it from there like any other c++ file for example. I installed Qt from the Nokia website and it was installed in /home/user/.QtSDK folder.

Thanks.

Comment: `find / | grep qmake` What's the output of that command?

Comment: after find / | grep qmake i get this:

http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=176570&c=6376950

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that the PyQt installer cannot find the qmake executable.
Running these two commands should solve it:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin/
export PATH
```

Afterwards, resume your installation.

Comment: I'm sorry it was my mistake when i said it doesn't work. I forgot to replace 'user' with my username. It works, thank you.

Comment: i have added PATH to my profile.sh file ..this solves my problem. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
make -q /home/user/.QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin/qmake
```

Does that work? I'm not sure if the error came up when you ran make, but I assume so. If not, add `-q /home/user/.QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin/qmake` to the proper command.

Comment: i get the error after running `python configure.py` from the terminal.

after running 
`make -q /home/user/.QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin/qmake` 
i get 
`make: *** No rule to make target `/home/user/.QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin/qmake'.  Stop.`

Also tried:
`python -q /home/user/.QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin/qmake configure.py`
but i got 
`Unknown option: -q
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.`

Comment: @JohnSmith Then do `python configure.py -q /home/user/.QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin/qmake`.