# Error while installing PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I want to install PyQt to use features of the Qt-library for my Python programms. When I execute 'configure.py' in the command window I get the following error:

`Error: Make sure you have a working Qt qmake on your PATH.`

About my system and what I've done yet: I use Python 3.2 on Windows 7.
First I compiled sip-4.15.5. After getting the error above, I also installed Qt5.2.1. Both installations worked without a problem, but the error stayed the same.

I have tried a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854599/pyqt-setup-for-qt-4-7-4) for apparently the same problem, found on stackoverflow. But it doesn't work for me (`export`isn't a windows command, is it?). And I don't use the PyQt installer, because it's only available for Python 2.7 and 3.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a PyQt installer for Python 3.2 [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt) at Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository. Whenever I'm looking to install or update a module on Windows, I look there first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed it, tomorrow I'll try it.

Comment: @julian - glad I could help. If my answer helped solve your problem, please click the check mark next to it to mark it as correct. It will also indicate that your issue was addressed to others that may have the same or a similar question. Finally, we both get [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) points from it. For more information, check out [What does it mean when an answer is accepted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @MattDMo How to install .whl files on windows?

Comment: @AvinashRaj [`pip install really_long_file_name.whl`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#installing-from-wheels)