# PyQt-win-gpl-4.11.1 installation

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pyqt4, qmake

I saw there was a [previous question about installing PyQt on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854599/pyqt-setup-for-qt-4-7-4), but unfortunately I'm not quite able to comment on the thread so I had to post a new question. Like that user, I have been having issues downloading QT 4.11.1. I downloaded SIP as well as PyQT4 ([link to instructions](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html)), but when I try to run `python configure-ng.py` from my downloads folder, I keep getting the same error saying:

`Error: Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake.`

Unfortunately I can't find the Qt settings which means I can't keep following the directions from the previous answer and I was hoping someone might be able to help walk me through how to download this module. Sorry for the duplication and thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you don't need to compile anything, because there are binary packages available that include everything you need (except for python itself). Just go to the [download page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) and select the installer that is appropriate for your system.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using a Mac. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, in that case, you seem to have the wrong source code. The error message is asking you to supply a path to the qmake executable on your system. Have you actually installed Qt yet?